# Self is set for the controller instead of the instance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating a simple url shorterer app. In the model I have method which creates short_url to be used instead of original url.

```
class ShortenersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :find_shortener, only: [:info, :show] 
    before_action :generate_unigue_shorty, only: [:create]
    def new
        @shortener = Shortener.new
    end

    def create
        @shortener = Shortener.new
        @shortener.main_url = params[:main_url]

        if @shortener.save
            redirect_to info_path(@shortener.short_url)
        else
            flash[:notice] = "Someting went wrong"
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    private
    def shortener_params
        params.require(:shortener).permit(:main_url, :short_url)
    end

    def find_shortener
        @shortener = Shortener.find_by_short_url(params[:short_url])
    end
end
```

Model:

```
class Shortener < ApplicationRecord
  before_create :generate_unique_shorty
    def generate_unique_shorty
      shorty = SecureRandom.hex(4)
        if  Shortener.all.any? {|a| a.short_url == shorty}
            self.generate_unique_shorty
        else
            self.short_url = shorty
        end
    end
end
```

The error i get:
**undefined method `generate_unigue_shorty' for #ShortenersController:0x00007fbfbc735db0** It looks like the self object in this method is set as Controller object, and It should be Instance of the Shortener class(@shortener)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo here: `generate_unigue_shorty`
g => q

Also there is no method called `generate_unique_shorty` in your controller. A `before_action` *in a controller* does look for the method *in the controller*, not in the model.

This being said, since you already have a `before_create` callback in your model that does generate a uniq shorty, no need to duplicate this behavior in the controller.

TL;DR: Remove `before_action :generate_unigue_shorty, only: [:create]` from your controller.

There are more things to re-think in your code that I'm not covering since that'd be off-topic

Comment: That was the line that should be deleted, after I moved this method from the controller to the model. I changed the name of the function when I was creating the post(to be correct) but it also help me. Thank you